# No overload for method 'Fill' takes 2 arguments in reporting c#

Tags: c#

i had use two dataset of same table and use two reportviewer but the problem is occuring that it isn't taking the second argument of fill as a different method.

```
private void search_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dateTime = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime);
        string dateTime2 = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString();
        DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime2);
        this.FeesPaymentTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet2.FeesPayment, dt, dt2);

        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }

    private void searchstatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.FeesPaymentTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet3.FeesPayment, this.cb.SelectedItem.ToString());
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DataSet2.FeesPayment' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

        this.reportViewer2.RefreshReport();
    }
```

the first one is working but the searchstatus buttons fill method isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second call to `Fill()` has only 2 arguments, the error message states that there is no overload that takes 2 arguments. Look at the overloads ans see what you need to pass as the third argument, you may be able to pass a null value or empty string...

Comment: how sir? i couldn't get it your answer?

Comment: Are you using visual studio? If so you can "peek definition" of the Fill() function (right click on the method name), this will show you all the possible overload methods.  You really need to know the data types allowed for the third argument.

Comment: it isn't taking the dataset third value it is showing this error.when i change the method name from fill to fills. 'WindowsFormsApplication1.DataSet2TableAdapters.FeesPaymentTableAdapter' does not contain a definition for 'Fills' and no extension method 'Fills' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.DataSet2TableAdapters.FeesPaymentTableAdapter' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)